# How to handle a form close event in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have used the below code but its not showing the msgbox. What is wrong with this code ?

```
Private Sub frmSimple_Disposed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Disposed
       Dim result = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to Exit ?", vbYesNo)
       If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        me.Close()
       End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This code runs after the form has been closed, when it's being disposed.
Depending on how you're showing the form, it might not get disposed at all.

You need to handle the `FormClosing` event and set `e.Cancel` to `True` if you want to cancel the close.

Comment: `If result = DialogResult.No Then e.Cancel = True`

Comment: click your form then in Properties Panel click events and then double click Form Closing event.this will prompt you to add code while your form is closing...and here you add your code

Comment: Getting Error : 'Cancel' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs'

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that. Works like a charm :D

Answer (score 7):

```
  Private Sub frmProgramma_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sur to close this application?", "Close", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
    Else
      e.Cancel = True
    End If
  End Sub
```

or that is how i use it everytime over and over...

Answer (score 3):

Use `FormClosing` event. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
 Dim result = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to Exit ?", vbYesNo)

       If result = vbYes Then
        me.Close()
       End If
```

Answer (score 2):

```
If MessageBox.Show("¿Exit?", "Application, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, _
                        MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.No Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is more clean and simply!

```
If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to Exit ?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then e.Cancel = True
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may not be 'efficient' but allows the user to save their work before closing, close the form if they press 'No' or return back to the form without closing if they press 'Cancel'.

```
        Dim dialog As DialogResult
        dialog = MessageBox.Show("Save before closing?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
        If dialog = DialogResult.Yes Then
            'Put a save file dialog here or Button.PerformClick() if you already have a save button programmed
        ElseIf dialog = DialogResult.No Then
            Application.Exit()
        ElseIf dialog = DialogResult.Cancel Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
```