# Need to break infinite loop when Form4 is closed

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, loops

`Form4` contains `PictureBox` refresh code that refreshes selected pictures one by one in 2-sec interval. This is made possible by giving a loop to 1000 value while the variable is increasing by 10. This loop needs to break when `Form4` is closed. 
`ListBox1` items contain the path of the images selected via openfiledialogue. 
wait and refresh of images is working fine.

I have tried every way possible to detect if the form is closed or the application is closed. Those failed very badly. But I do believe there is a way to break the loop when the user is returned to `form1`[Main menu].

Tried `Application.openforms.count` way and it is not possible to add it in the for each loop as it is giving 0 value.

It is also possible not to have messages here and get the text just displayed to richtextbox but still when the windows form application is closed the application will still run till `g = 1000` and will be active in the task manager.

Hence a break is needed for the do while loop.

```
Do Until g = 1000
                For Each Item In ListBox1.Items
                    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Item)
                    PictureBox1.Refresh()
                    PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
                    '  g = g + 10
                   ' MsgBox(Item)

                    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup(Item, 1, "Title")
                    wait(2)


                Next
                ' need to break here if the form is closed. 
Loop

 Private Sub wait(ByVal seconds As Integer)
        For i As Integer = 0 To seconds * 100
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
            Application.DoEvents()
        Next
 End Sub
```

Break in the loop is needed by a condition that when that particular form is closed then break the loop.

Comment: Can you add the code that you use to create/display the form to the question, please? Also, take a look at this question [How to handle a form close event in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805335/how-to-handle-a-form-close-event-in-vb-net). The answers describe how to detect when a form is closed

Comment: Hello JayV, I have already taken a look over that and it was not that much helpful. From form1 I call form4 like this. 
' Dim myform As Form4
        myform = New Form4
               myform.Show(Form4)'

Comment: Would it not be better to create a timer with a static variable to increase the value on each tick and add an `If` statement to exit the loop if the form is closing - `If Me.Closing Then` disable the timer and exit the `For` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If Me.IsDisposed Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
```

This at

```
Do Until g = 1000


                For Each Item In ListBox1.Items
                    ' If tf.Contains("WindowsApplication6.Form4, Text: Form4") Then
                    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Item)

                    PictureBox1.Refresh()
                    PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
                    g = g + 10
                    'MsgBox(Item)
                    RichTextBox1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Item)

                    'RichTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
                    '  RichTextBox1.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
                    '  RichTextBox1.Font = New Font(RichTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
                    'CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup(Item, 1, "Title")
                    wait(2)


                Next
               ' here 
                If Me.IsDisposed Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
```

Magically this was only needed in the code to break properly. 
Thanks to everyone who have supported me in solving this problem by your valuable comments.

Comment: You should use a Timer (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`) and updated whatever you need to updated in its `Tick` event. In the `Form.FormClosed` event, stop and dispose of the Timer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Timer component? Add a Timer component to your form. Set the Interval property to (milliseconds) 2000. It will stop ticking when your form closed; no loop to worry about.

```vb
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Static Index As Integer 'Static preserves the value between calls to the method
    If Index > ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then
        Index = 0 'will start the display over again
        'If you want to stop at the final image just Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If
    Dim Item = ListBox1.Items(Index).ToString

    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Item.ToString)
    PictureBox1.Refresh()
    PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    'Option Strict does not like the following line
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup(Item, 1, "Title")
    Index += 1
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks perfect. But the problem is solved by just me.isdisposed method.
Thanks for providing me this info.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Form4` class define private bool variable and then define `Dispose` method of your class in following way:

```
Public Class Form4
    Private _isFormClosed = False
    'rest of your code here
    Public Overloads Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        _isFormClosed = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then just use the bool variable in your loop to break it.

Other way would be to use [`FormClosing` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing?view=netframework-4.7.2) and setting value of the boolean variable there.

Comment: Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

Error 1 'Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)' has multiple definitions with identical signatures. 
Thanks for joining me in this problem!. This error is thrown when I have added your overloads sub and Do break condition with isformclosed variable. 
let me know if any more info is needed.

Comment: Plus let me add that I have already been through form closing event and that was not much helpful in breaking the loop there.

Comment: What you posted is NOT what I posted in my answer. I totally don't understand what are you trying to do. You complaining about mine code and paste code, which is totally different from mine. What is you rproblem?

Comment: ok first. I am sorry. That code was pointing to Dispose designer element the correction I have made by calling it Dispose2 have solved that error. The code in last comment was of form4 designer dispose system method.
Plus I have properly put break of isformclosed in the Do until loop
 If _isFormClosed = True Then
                    Exit Do

                End If
Now there are no errors but the application is still waiting after it is closed. For the code the break is still not occurring. :(

Comment: You need to add a line of code inside your loop that says 'If _isFormClosed Then Exit Do', or similar.

Comment: Have added its still not breaking the loop. I am still working around it to make it work properly.  Thanks Grim for joining the problem.